# How To Remove Several Nested Objects Using an Array of ToDeleteItems

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to use a checklist to select locations from a collection and store them into an array called ToDelete : [{_id: String}]. With that array I want to run it against the locations inside of a Collections object and remove them.

I store the Collection ID as a param and the array as the body. I have console logged the array so I know it has the ID's I want to delete and correctly passes them to the service.

What should my server side function look like with mongoose? This is my best attempt.

```
//DELETE COLLECTION LOCATIONS
collectionRouter.post('removeLocation/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  Collection.update(
    {_id: req.params.id},
    {$pull: {locations: {_id: {$in:req.body}}}},
    function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
          title: 'An error occured',
          error: err
        });
      }
      res.status(201).json({
        message: 'Locations Removed',
        obj: result
      });
    });
});
```

Here is my Collection.Service

```
removeCollectionLocation(collection: Collection, locations: string[])  {
    let body = locations;
    const headers = new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
      ? '?token=' + localStorage.getItem('token')
      : '';
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/collection/removeLocation/' + collection._id + token , body, {headers: headers})
      .map((response: Response)=> response.json())
      .catch((error: Response)=> Observable.throw(error.json()));
  }
```

Thank you everyone.

Comment: this is okie , observing no issue in function above .

Comment: :( 
main.bundle.js:576 TypeError: error.json is not a function
    at CatchSubscriber.selector

and it returns a code of 200 which is none of the code's I have provided

Comment: yes but you can use response.json({ isSuccess:false, err:err })  for logging the error part without crashing your functions

Comment: @hardy Thank you, at what part of the collection service do I place it in? I tossed it in the response.json function from my map but it says the arguments are wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can Do Something like this -

```
removeCollectionLocation(collection: Collection, locations: string[])  {
    let body = locations;
    const headers = new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
      ? '?token=' + localStorage.getItem('token')
      : '';
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/collection/removeLocation/' + collection._id + token , body, {headers: headers})
      .map((response: Response)=> response.json())
      .catch(error => Observable.of(`Bad Promise: ${error}`));
  }
```

Comment: turns out i needed a '/' before my route.